# Vaadin Google Description

Tags: java, seo, vaadin

I developed a webapp with Vaadin. After go-live for a few weeks, i try to search in Google. I had to improve my google rating. But this is another problem.

After a few searches i found my website in google on the second site. But there is no description? How can I set the description in Google?
Is it right, that this description is the HTML-Meta-Tag from the website?
If it is correct, how can i set it in Vaadin?

I tried to set it to my main window, but i can´t see any changes.

```
mainWindow.setDescription("test description");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I search a lot of time.
I found some workarounds but i think it is to circuitous. The best solution is to make a background side which has includes the content, but i don´t know how google find this one. My solution is to develop the my website with HTML, CSS, JS etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think any web 2.0 framework will give problems for google.
Do retrieve your website with wget or similar and look what your server returns.

Comment: I have done it already. There is only a javascript call. But how can i fix this probolem? I had to improve SEO for my Vaadin-Application, but i don´t know, if this is possible.